# How do i use a custom font in a fragment layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, custom-font

*Edit

I think it has to do something with Android 5.0.2. I tried it with an activity, and it gives me the same error.

So I'm new to the navigation drawer and fragments. Everything works fine and now I want to have a textview with a custom font. Normally it works with the method below, but now it doesn't.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // I use this everytime for normal layouts, but with a fragment layout it doesnt work
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHome);  
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "impact.ttf");  
    txt.setTypeface(font); 



    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    return rootView;


}
}
```

The errors I get are:

```
The method getAssets() is undefined for the type HomeFragment
The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type HomeFragment
```

As I'm new to android programming, I really want a solution and want to understand why it's wrong. All help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You just need to change a few things.  You need to inflate the view first before getting its children, and also get the activity to get the assets:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

  public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    TextView txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHome);  
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "impact.ttf");  
    txt.setTypeface(font); 

    return rootView;


}
}
```

Comment: @DyRight - Please accept the answer if this is right answer.  :)

Comment: For some reason when i try to run the app it gives me the error "Font not found" does this has anything to do with the new android lollipop? I never had an error like this before. Tried multiple fonts now, still no good.

Comment: Is the font in the assets folder?

Comment: Yeah, assets/fonts/impact.ttf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84001/discussion-between-dyright-and-kristy-welsh).

Comment: I think you just need to specify the fonts folder: Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/impact.ttf");

Answer (score 0):

Just do this change it will work.

```
 public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
 public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {


TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHome);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "impact.ttf");  
txt.setTypeface(font); 



View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

return rootView;
 }
                                         }
```

Here getActivity() will give you the context, From this context you can access the assets folder. It will work :)

Comment: It still gives me the error : "Font not found " but the font is in the assets/font folder, the name is correct. i tried different fonts too, but they all give me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding s to font , like  assets/fonts